# Laravel 8 - Error while trying to output values from my array that stores objects

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, laravel-8

I am a beginner in the Laravel framework and I am having a problem with my code. I made a function in my Project model that stores some data objects from the database inside an array.

```
public function list()
{
    $userType = DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', Auth::user()->type)->first();
    $data = array();
    $i = 0;

    if ($userType == 0 || $userType == 1) {
        $devproject = DB::table('dev_project')->where('id_dev', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
        foreach ($devproject as $project) {
            $data[$i] = DB::select('select * from projects where id = '.$project->id_project.';');
            $i++;
        }
        return $data;
    } else {
        return 'error';
    }
}
```

The data array has the value of two objects from the DB rows that are supposed to be inside of it, in the tests that I am making. Can you tell me why this error occurs, and how can I print the values of my array? The problem is when I try to output those values in my view.

```
@foreach(Project::list() as $project)
    <tr><a class="text-item" href="#">{{$project->name}}</a></tr>
@endforeach
```

This gives me the following error and I don't understand why since I think `$project` should be an object.

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: First you have made mistake here `if($userType == 0 || $userType == 1){`  because `userType` not return `0` or `1`. It will return full `users` object data.

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya the thing is that this variable does not output anything. But the if statement still works.

Comment: Yes it works because you have used `or` condition with true and false.

Comment: You should debug your code. like `$devproject` return data or not? `dd($devproject)`

Comment: What exactly does `Project::list()` return?

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya i figured what was wrong in that regard out. Thank you for pointing out the problem!

Comment: @lolflexgameplays What was the actual problem?

Comment: @Alex it returns an array containing two objects, each containing every variable from the database. Exacty this: [[{"id":2,"name":"jjjj","starting_date":"2022-01-21","limit_date":"2022-04-30","type":0,"created_at":"2022-01-21 16:40:00","updated_at":"2022-01-21 16:40:00"}],[{"id":3,"name":"china","starting_date":"2022-01-21","limit_date":"2022-05-31","type":1,"created_at":"2022-01-21 17:09:52","updated_at":"2022-01-21 17:09:52"}]]

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya The `'id'` in `where('id', '=', Auth::user()->type)` was supposed to be `'type'`, and here `if($userType == 0 || $userType == 1)` it should be `$userType->type`

Comment: @lolflexgameplays Both your objects are wrapped in another array, meaning `$project` in your template is an array, not an object. You have to make sure the result of `DB::select()` returns one item instead of an array.